# timeout error in BI tool

Tags: soql, data

There is an external BI tool which reads or extracts data from Salesforce and produces report. However, since 1 week the delta load or data load to BI is failing where it returns time out error.

This as far as we understand is possibly because of sudden increase of volume of data in SFDC. Could you please help how to troubleshoot these kind of issue and from where the optimization is needed, is it in BI tool or in Salesforce dealing with LDV? Please note, there is an automated sql job which loads these data to BI from SFDC.

Comment: are u using power query in excel?what is the BI tool in context?

Comment: It is a Power BI tool Rodis one from Microsoft. I am not sure about power query being used which I will discuss with BI team since we look Salesforce aspects.